# Knockout observable only updates once inside jquery form

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm using jQuery to upload a file from the client to my server.  Then, I'm using Knockout to get the filename and get information from the file that's now on the server.  However, I'm having two problems:

1. The knockout observable "filename" only gets updated once, the first time a file is selected.
2. The file name is not being displayed.

I know this has something to do with the interaction of Knockout and jQuery, but I haven't been able to figure out what.  I'm using Knockout 2.2.1, jQuery 1.9.2, and the File Upload from [here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).  I haven't been able to replicate it with jsFiddle yet; when I do, I'll update my question.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        'use strict';
        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload();
    });
</script>
<div id="fileupload">
    <form action="FileUploadHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" data-bind="value: filename"/>
    </form>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Upload" data-bind="click: uploadFile">
```

KO:

```
self.filename = ko.observable("");
self.uploadFile = function () {
    if (self.filename() == "") {
        alert('Please choose a file to upload.');
    }
    else {
        promiseLoad = callLoad();
        $.when(
                promiseLoad
            )
            .done(function () {
                showHide('LoadingPanel', false, true);
            });
    }
};

self.callLoad = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
        service.callServiceMethod("GetTempData", JSON.stringify({
            Filename: self.filename()
        }), function (msg) {
            if (msg.d.Alert) {
                alert("Success");
            };
            dfd.resolve();
        });
    }).promise();
};
```

Note: the actual uploading is happening via the FileUploadHandler.ashx, and that does not have the same problems as the knockout (files selected after the first are uploaded correctly, but do not update filename).

Comment: Where is your KO code?

Comment: Can you share your javascript code? Also, you are missing a '"' in here -><input type="file" name="files[]" data-bind="value: filename />

Comment: Added. The quote was present in my file; I just copied it over incorrectly.

Comment: where are how are you assigning the value for filename?

Comment: Within the file input. The data-bind sets the filename to the value in the input.

Comment: What makes you think Knockout is able to change the `value` of a file upload `input`?

Comment: "The value binding links the associated DOM element’s value with a property on your view model. This is typically useful with form elements such as <input>, <select> and <textarea>." As found on the KO site [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html). Besides which, I'm not trying to get Knockout to update the file input, I'm trying to get the file input to update Knockout.

Comment: I'm guessing the `fileupload` plugin replaces the actual `input` element, making knockout loose any potential bindings (the commens in the code says: "By default, the file input field is replaced with a clone after each input field change event. This is required for iframe transport queues and allows change events to be fired for the same file selection [...]"). You should probably create a custom bindingHandler which applies the `fileupload` to the dom element and also allows other bindings, if you want that. Many jQuery plugins replace DOM elements and therefore need custom bindingHandlers.

Comment: I believe Robert is correct. I'm using a different file upload widget that does just that (replaces DOM elements) and have had to create a custom binding. In fact, I've had to do the same with the CKEditor and a color picker plug in which replace or add to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both problems can be fixed by setting replaceFileInput in the jQuery file upload to false, rather than true.  When true, the value is cloned and the file name does not display; when false, the value stays as it is (letting it be bound to KO) and displays normally.  (Thanks to the commenters for putting me on the right track.)